# Add blur background without Aero effect

Tags: c#, winforms

I had been searching around StackOverflow to find an article that can help me achieve this Winform blur effect:

[image: An Example of Blur Effect from UWP DevKit]

This is a Winform I made (with online tutorial) and it has an ugly Aero GLASS effect (the glossy glass overlay) and uncustomizable blur intensity and color.

[image: Here is the image].

So now I'm looking for a way to apply the above Blur effect to the winform.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096609/c-sharp-how-to-make-a-windows-7-aero-winform-blured-glass).

Comment: @Sandeep I'm confused. Which part? I can't find the part that can help me remove the glossy glass from Aero and make the blur intensity customizable. Sorry :(

Comment: The answer added by Cody Gray has a [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17681/Windows-Vista-Aero-Glass-in-NET-Managed-Win-Appl) to `CodeProject`. You may find that useful.

Comment: Take a look at this answer I posted a couple of months ago: [Borderless Form Dropshadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395005/borderless-form-dropshadow/49418946#49418946). It's about a borderless windows that's using the Aero DropShadow. But, by mistake, inside the WinApi declarations I left a number of other functions, among which also wrappers for `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow`, `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` etc. If it's not exactly what you're looking for, you'll have the base for  DWM API calls, anyway.