# Blur effect for WinForm - Issue with solution

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, .net-4.8, dwm

I know this question have been answered with several ways but I am making this separate question in order to avoid potential queue of comments under initial question and its answers with which I am facing an "issue"(?).

---

What I am trying to achieve (*in my case*) is to apply what is called the **Windows Blur Effect** to a borderless WinForm.

[image]

I found **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69410550/6336312)** answer by **[György Kőszeg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5114784/gy%C3%B6rgy-k%C5%91szeg)** to a similar **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51370670/6336312)** and I adapted his code to my project like this:

First I made this `BlurEffect` class:

```csharp
internal class BlurEffect
{
    internal enum AccentState
    {
        ACCENT_DISABLED = 0,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT = 1,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT = 2,
        ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND = 3,
        ACCENT_INVALID_STATE = 4
    }

    internal enum WindowCompositionAttribute
    {
        WCA_ACCENT_POLICY = 19
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct AccentPolicy
    {
        public AccentState AccentState;
        public int AccentFlags;
        public int GradientColor;
        public int AnimationId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct WindowCompositionAttributeData
    {
        public WindowCompositionAttribute Attribute;
        public IntPtr Data;
        public int SizeOfData;
    }

    internal static class User32
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern int SetWindowCompositionAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, ref WindowCompositionAttributeData data);
    }

    internal static void Apply(Form form, bool enable)
    {
        var accent = new AccentPolicy { AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND };
        if (!enable)
            accent = new AccentPolicy { AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_DISABLED };
        var accentStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(accent);
        var accentPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(accentStructSize);

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(accent, accentPtr, false);

        var data = new WindowCompositionAttributeData
        {
            Attribute = WindowCompositionAttribute.WCA_ACCENT_POLICY,
            SizeOfData = accentStructSize,
            Data = accentPtr
        };

        User32.SetWindowCompositionAttribute(form.Handle, ref data);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(accentPtr);
    }
}
```

And then, into my test `Form`, I added a `property` and a `button` so to enable or disable the **Blur Effect**:

```csharp
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private bool blur_effect = false;
    [Category("• MyForm")]
    [DisplayName("• BlurEffect")]
    [Description("Enables or disables the [Blur] effect.")]
    public bool BlurEffect
    {
        get => this.blur_effect;
        set
        {
            this.blur_effect = value;
            BlurEffect.Apply(this, value);
            base.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BlurEffect_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BlurEffect = !this.BlurEffect;
    }
}
```

As you can see on the image below, it "worked" but I had this "issue"(?). Along with the `form`, the **Βlur Effect** is applied to the controls as well. Is that normal? Is there something I can do so the **Blur Effect** applies on the `form` only?

***Note**: Form's shadow comes from another class!!!*

[image]

Comment: As [mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580871/7444103), the *effect* you can achieve with blur-behind in this Platform is not state-of-the-art. The drop-shadow of a border-less Form is also not perfect, because of the transparent / invisible borders applied to a Window (a drop shadow of 2 pixels is however *tolerable*) -- A simple patch is a *sandwich* of two Forms, overlaying your blurred Form to a border-less one which has its Opacity set to, e.g. 35~50 % and move it as your Form moves. Then child Controls are not translucent anymore. Must be positioned perfectly...

Comment: ... considering the transparent borders (or the drop-shadow borders you have specified), otherwise you'll see sort of a phantom of the external sides of the border-less Form behind your blurred Form

Comment: This is a normal "issue" when you use Winforms controls.  Text rendering in Winforms is done by GDI, fundamentally a 24bpp api.  You need a 32bpp api to avoid this artifact, DirectWrite is the usual choice.  Problem is, once you fixed all the controls to use it, you'd have basically reinvented Winforms.  WPF uses a 32bpp api, best way to get ahead.