# Gaussian translucent effect in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, gaussian, translucency

Is there a easy way to make a gaussian translucent effect for a form in VB.Net?
I searched on web but there are very difficult codes.
Sorry for my English, i'm studying it.
Thank you.

Comment: [`Form.Opacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.opacity) - Makes the entire form and all its controls translucent. If you only want the form itself to be translucent you'd have to switch from WinForms to WPF.

Comment: If you're referring to WinForms, the nice thing about it is that you have to do a lot of things yourself. Transparency is one of those. See here one method about Form translucency [How to create a semi transparent or blurred backcolor on windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51578104/c-sharp-how-to-create-a-semi-transparent-or-blurred-backcolor-on-windows-form?answertab=active#tab-top). Another related to WinForms Controls translucency: [Circle with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396681/circle-with-text?answertab=active#tab-top). Yes, `C#`, but convertible.