# C# How to set form transparency that does not affect buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

[image]

```
this.Opacity = 0.7;
this.metroTextBox1.Opacity = 1.0;
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: WinForms and transparency are practically incompatible. If you really need it, then switch to some other GUI framework.

Comment: Maybe you will be satisfied with the [TransparencyKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey?view=net-5.0) property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050249/transparency-for-windows-forms-textbox

Comment: See also the `DwmSetWindowAttribute()` *version* here: [How to create a semi transparent or blurred backcolor in a Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580871/7444103)