# Making form transparent without losing border transparency [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I would like to know if it is possible to make the Form transparent **without** the Border (where the minimize button is and all that) being transparent too? If it is, how can I do it?

Or Without losing transparency for some controls like buttons on form.

[image]

Comment: You can make it fully transparent by setting the `TransparencyKey` but you cannot adjust the opacity of the client area alone, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: [How to create a semi transparent or blurred backcolor in a Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580871/7444103)  (you can find a number of other functions there that create other effects, as the *Sheet Of Glass* and a `WindowBorderlessDropShadow()` method. The images just show the `BlurBehind` effect, for Windows 7 and Windows 10) -- But you may want to build an UWP app instead :) The acrylic effect is better, IMO. WPF can also do a good job, with almost no *effort*.