# Semi-transparent form background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

im making a WinForms app but i dont know how to make a semi-transparent form background like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L35Dv.png)

Please help me

Comment: It is not really possible in Winforms. - One common workaround is to overlay two forms, one normal and one with Opacity < 100..

Comment: [How to create a semi transparent or blurred backcolor in a Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580871/7444103) -- You can play with it, to get different results

Comment: @Jimi i don't want use the Windows DWM blur. Draw bugs...